# Shopify + ROR + Unable to retrieve product list and send to view using proxy in Shopify front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, shopify

I am new to Shopify app development and ROR. I am working on a Shopify App, Where I need to display the product details along with additional info on a customer page (Front end). From the official doc I understand it can be done using proxy. I have also feeded my proxy URL (URL, sub path etc...) to my app.

And I am able to view my proxy page within my Shopify store. But while I collect custom product list in controller it throws,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Failed to open TCP connection to dfbcde0b66b220d0b8b1da94205cea9c:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known))
```

error. And also the retrieved data could not be accessed in view.

Here is my controller

```
class PersonalizerController < ApplicationController
    include ShopifyApp::AppProxyVerification
    include ShopifyAPI
  def index
    @shop = ShopifyApp::SessionRepository.retrieve(2)
    ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(@shop)
    ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
    ShopifyAPI::Base.site = "https://#{ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key}:#"+@shop.token+"@#{params[:shop]}/admin"
    if(params[:pid].present?)
        @fonts = Font.order('id DESC')
        @shapes = Shape.order('id DESC')
        @clipartcategories = Clipartcategory.order('id DESC')
        // This line is causing TCP error
        @pdt = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:pid]) 
        @product_id = params[:pid]
        @productoption = Productoption.where(product_id: params[:pid])
    else
        puts "hello"
    end
  end 
end
```

I am stuck with this for the whole day, any suggestion or Am I miss understood the concept. Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is bad

`"https://#{ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key}:#"+@shop.token+"@#{params[:shop]}/admin"`

This is how you do  extrapolation in ruby.

`"https://#{ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key}:#{@shop.token}#{params[:shop]}/admin"`